# Vue router with one+ paramaters as an array ? (for tree exploration)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I'm working on an app that allows the user to explore a tree of folders & files. And I would like the urls to look like `http://myapp/explore/idfolder1/idfolderx/idfolderb` when I'm currently in the folderb that is in the folderx that is is the folder1. So that when one user copy/paste an URL to one of his collegue, he can access the ressource with the breadcrumbs as well.

But it can be from one folder deep to many many folders deep.

I'm not sure how to code this in the vue router. Some kind of path: `'explore/[:folderIds]'` so I can access my array of "path" via `this.$route.params.folderIds` (= ['idfolder1', 'idfolderx', 'idfolderb'] in my exemple) ? This was a wild guess and it is not working.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use the path: `path: '/explore/*'`.

You can then use `this.$route.params.pathMatch` to receive the params.

`this.$route.params.pathMatch.split('/').filter(x => x)` if you need it as array.

Source: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes.

Comment: this solution will work for what I describred. However it feels like a hack, and have some downsides. For instance, I won't be able to do proper routing with something like `:to="{ name: 'Explore', params: { folderIds: ... }}"`. Any idea for pretty routing with this kind of path ?